# Iterate every two elements in ruby for loop

Tags: ruby

How do you create a for loop like

```
for (int x=0; x<data.length; x+=2)
```

in ruby? I want to iterate through an array but have my counter increment by two instead of one.

Comment: It would be good if you show the inside of the `for` loop. Then you might get a better answer..

Answer (score 44):

If what you really want is to consume 2 items from an array at a time, check out [each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].each_slice(2) do |a, b|
  puts "#{a}, #{b}"
end

# result
1, 2
3, 4
5, 6
7, 8
9,
```

Comment: Obviously, if you want, you can just ignore `b`. But you still have to include it into the `|a, b|` block parameters otherwise he will fit the slice of two elements into the array `a` in `|a|`.

Comment: Even better, use `|a, *b|`. Then you can change the argument to `each_slice` to get every 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc. element.

Comment: The Ruby way to deal with a single unwanted variable in the incoming parameter list, is to use the `_` black-hole. In other languages, like Perl, it's very commonly used as a temporary variable, and Ruby *can* do that too, but we don't because it's confusing. It does come in very handy though for things like `|a, _|` and then ignore it from there. A more accepted way to do it with more recent Rubies is `|a, *|` which will gobble multiple values.

Comment: This idiom is even built into the interpreter: unused local variables will trigger a warning, unless they start with `_`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag it's even more than that:

    `(1...10).to_a.each_slice(3){|a, c, c| puts  a}` will throw an error; `(1...10).to_a.each_slice(3){|a, _, _| puts  a}` works no problem.

Comment: @JohnLedbetter: … and so does `|a, _c, _c|`. Interesting.

Answer (score 8):

Ruby's [`step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step) is your friend:

```
0.step(data.length, 2).to_a
=> [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

I'm using `to_a` to show what values this would return. In real life [`step` is an enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Numeric.html#method-i-step), so we'd use it like:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
0.step(data.length, 2).each do |i|
  puts data[i]
end
```

Which outputs:

```
0
2
4
   <== a nil
```

Notice that `data` contains six elements, so `data.length` returns `6`, but an array is a zero-offset, so the last element would be element #5. We only get three values, plus a nil which would display as an empty line when printed, which would be element #6:

```
data[6]
=> nil
```

That's why we don't usually walk arrays and container using outside iterators in Ruby; It's too easy to fall off the end. Instead, use `each` and similar constructs, which always do the right thing.

To continue to use `step` and deal with the zero-offset for arrays and containers, you could use:

```
0.step(data.length - 1, 2)
```

but I'd still try working with `each` and other array iterators as a first choice, which [@SergioTulentsev was giving as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18338571/128421).

Answer (score 2):

```
(0..data.length).step(2) do |x|
puts x
end
```

This seems like the closest substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`Range#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-step):

```
a = (1..50).to_a
(1..a.size).step(2).map{|i| a[i-1]} # [1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ...
```